# WSO2 4.8.0 ESB conditional router

Tags: filter, wso2, conditional-statements, router, wso2-esb

i read at this url

https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Sample+157:+Conditional+Router+for+Routing+Messages+based+on+HTTP+URL,+HTTP+Headers+and+Query+Parameters

that conditional router matching a regex can be written like this:

```
<match type="header" source="my_custom_header2" regex="bar.*"/>
```

where type can be header, url or param.
Can be used the body message as source? i have to evaluate something like this:

```
<match type="????" source="json-eval($.codice)" regex="0"/>
```

where type should the message body. Is it possible? or have i to use the FILTER mediator? i mean something like:

```
<filter xpath="/codice='OK'">
        <then>
           //DO SOMETHING
        </then>
        <else>
           DO ANOTHER THING
        </else>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things: Match only supports the types header, param and url. You will also not be able to use JSON Path on the match regardless of whether it supports message body.

You should go with filter if you are routing based on message body.